# Get particular key's and value's from JSON array - Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I am a beginner with Ruby, and I have the following Json array:

```
    "elements": [
        {
          "type": "Contact",          
          "id": "1",
          "createdAt": "131231235",
          "name": "test",
          "updatedAt": "1456328049",
          "accountName": "Mr Test",
          "country": "China",
          "firstName": "Test",
          "lastName": "lastNameTest",
        },
        {
          "type": "Contact",          
          "id": "2",
          "createdAt": "156453447",
          "name": "test2",
          "updatedAt": "124464554",
          "accountName": "Mr Test2",
          "country": "Germany",
          "firstName": "Test2",
          "lastName": "lastNameTest2",
            },...
]
```

I want to filter out only a few keys + values: for example I want to return only the id,name,accountName,firstname and lastname.

So the exspected output is the following:

```
    "elements": [
        {         
          "id": "1",
          "name": "test",
          "accountName": "Mr Test",
          "firstName": "Test",
          "lastName": "lastNameTest",
        },
        {      
          "id": "2",
          "name": "test2",
          "accountName": "Mr Test2",
          "firstName": "Test2",
          "lastName": "lastNameTest2",
            },...
]
```

I tried the following: create a filter array which has the elements I want to return and then map over the items but then I get stuck..

```
filters = []
filters.push("accountName")
filters.push("lastName")
filters.push("firstName")
filters.push("Id")

output["elements"].each do |item|
result = []
item.map {|key,value|filters.include? key}
result.push(?)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: A very important thing to understand is that JSON is merely a serialization mechanism, and when manipulating objects *expressed as JSON*, you should deserialize them (using JSON.parse), and operate on whatever Ruby objects are created.  Then, if you need JSON, you can use #to_json or JSON.pretty_generate to create the modified JSON.  So it's best to think "JSON *representation* of an array*" and not "JSON array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, you should be able to work out from this:

```
output = { "elements": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "test",
            "accountName": "Mr Test",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "lastNameTest",
            "somethoong": "sdsad"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "test2",
            "accountName": "Mr Test2",
            "firstName": "Test2",
            "lastName": "lastNameTest2"
            }
          ]}

attribs = %w(accountName lastName firstName id)
output[:elements].each do |item|
  item.delete_if{|k,v| !attribs.include?(k.to_s)}
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Alfie, not really familiair yet with the methods ruby offers.

Comment: output[:elements].each do |item|
      item.keep_if{|k,_| %i(accountName lastName firstName id).include? k }
    end

Comment: Also, if you are using Rails, you can `output["elements"].slice("accountName", "lastName", "firstName", "id")`.
Turns out `slice` is now included in Ruby 2.5 – https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8499